# Php stripos for finding two words in one url

Tags: php, stripos

I want this script to read each line (all are urls) from a text file and parse it to check whether two given words exist in any of the urls of that particular website. I also want all the urls (lines) in the text file be printed serially numbered. This code finds out the two words but I am not sure whether they are from the same url of that site. It displays the number of times the given words occur instead of the serial number.

```
<?php  
$mysearch = file("phpelist.txt");  

for($index = 0; $index <count($mysearch); $index++)  
{

    $mysearch[$index] = str_replace("\n", "", $mysearch[$index]);  
    $data = file_get_contents("$mysearch[$index]");  

    $searchTerm1 = 'about'; 

 if (stripos($data, $searchTerm1) !== false) {
     echo "$counter$.mysearch[$index]... FOUND WORD $searchTerm1<br>";
     $searchTerm2 = 'us';
     if (stripos($data, $searchTerm2) !== false) {
        echo "... FOUND WORD $searchTerm2<br>";
        } 
}    

    else
        { 
        echo "<br>";
        echo "$mysearch[$index]...not found<br>";
        }    
}
?>
```

The output of the script is as follows:

'url1'...not found

'url2'...not found

'url3'...not found

'url4'...not found

'url5'...not found
$.mysearch[5]... FOUND WORD about
... FOUND WORD us
$.mysearch[6]... FOUND WORD about
... FOUND WORD us
$.mysearch[7]... FOUND WORD about
... FOUND WORD us

'url6'...not found
$.mysearch[9]... FOUND WORD about
... FOUND WORD us
$.mysearch[10]... FOUND WORD about
... FOUND WORD us
$.mysearch[11]... FOUND WORD about
... FOUND WORD us
$.mysearch[12]... FOUND WORD about
... FOUND WORD us
$.mysearch[13]... FOUND WORD about
... FOUND WORD us

Comment: Why not give `&&`?

Comment: Is that a typo `$.mysearch`? Is this better `$mysearch`? Better do `{$counter}{$mysearch[$index]}`

Comment: And by the way: `$counter` is not defined

Comment: Thanks, I will use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a simple way by a function like this:

```
<?php
    function findWordsInString($str, $arr) {
        $found = array();
        foreach ($arr as $cur) {
            if (stripos($str, $cur) !== false)
                $found[$cur] = stripos($str, $cur);
        }
        return $found;
    }
?>
```

And then, with the returned value, you can run `array_keys` to get the string values that are found. The index of them stores the position.

Let's take an example:

```
$str = "Hello, world. How are you?";
$arr = array("Hello", "world", "you", "Hi");
```

This would give an output like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["Hello"]=>
  int(0)
  ["world"]=>
  int(7)
  ["you"]=>
  int(22)
}
```

Only `Hello`, `world`, and `you` are found in this case, and they are in the positions of `0`, `7`, and `22`.

Comment: What is $cur here? Thanks.

Comment: @ajeshkdy Current element.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$fp = file("phpelist.txt");
$urlList = file_get_contents($fp);
$urls = explode("\n", $urlList);

$counter = 0;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
  $counter++;
  if (preg_match_all('#\b(word1|word2)\b#',  $url, $matches)) {
      echo "line: $counter url : $url <br/>";
  }
}
```